# create android library project and use the generated jar

Tags: android, jar

I'm trying to create an android library and use it in another project. So far, the reference I can find is the one on [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

However, that documentation only teach how to create android library and reference the project to another project. What I want to achieve is something like google admob, where I can reference the jar version.

I've tried to use jar taken from `$PROJECTDIR/bin/` but it generate error saying the `R` class is not found.

Is there any way to create it? some tutorials, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is something like google admob, where I can reference the jar version.

That JAR does not have Android resources in it.

> Is there any way to create it?

Not at this time. Support for packaging an Android library project as a JAR, with resources included, is something they are working on, but it is not ready just yet.

Comment: the JAR files from admob has `R` in it.

Comment: @ariefbayu: `R` is a Java class. That JAR does not have Android resources in it.

Comment: yes, you are right. Upon further inspection, I see no xml in it.